# How do I see my image (BLOB) in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, blob, backend, mysql-workbench, data-storage

I am having trouble seeing my image. No matter what I do, it turns up null.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';
```

would give me
[image]

In that folder, I have a folder called Image, and then images (.jpg)

however,

```
select LOAD_FILE('\Image\agatti-airport-india2.jpg');
```

gives me

[image]

I've tried /Image/, ./Image/, Image/ , Image\ and all the variations.

I've also tried absolute path, which doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found an answer

1. You have to put the entire absolute path, that includes the show variables like "secure_file_priv";
2. You have to make sure you use forward slash (/) not backslash ()

In my case, `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Image/agatti-airport-india2.jpg` would be correct. I still don't know why absolute paths to other paths would not work